# GqlQuery and ID

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, gqlquery

I try to build a GqlQuery and get an entity by the specified ID, but I get the error "IndexError: The query returned fewer than 1 results".
A DataStore is not empty. At the Datastore Viewer I've found the necessary ID.
My code is placed below:

from google.appengine.ext import db
from models.models import News

news = News.gql("WHERE id = 4265")

print news[0].title

---

I know about the get_by_id method, by some reasons it is not satisfied me. But English is not native for me, because of this I didn't understand how to properly use Key.from_path.

Comment: I've tried to do little otherwise. But, I still get the same error.
Below is my new code:

k = db.Key.from_path('News', 4264)

news = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM News WHERE key =:1", k)

news[0].title

Comment: You have a few pretty basic errors, you should probably familiarise yourself with [GQL](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) and the various [handy methods on Model](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_id)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
news = News.get_by_id(4265)
if news is not None: 
  print news.title
```

Or if you must use GQL,

```
news = News.get(db.Key.from_path('News', 4265))
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to write a Gql query, when you can just use [get_by_id()](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/modelclass.html#Model_get_by_id) method of Model Class.

**note:** id can be get from a object by object.Key().id() inside python and in templates you simply call object.key.id

```
news = News.get_by_id(4265)
```

or you can use [db.Key.from_path](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/keyclass.html) to get the key and pass it to get() method.

`new = News.get(db.Key.from_path('News', 4265))`